# Drupal commons running very slow, what are the key modules to disable?

Tags: 7

I'm running [Drupal commons](http://www.acquia.com/products-services/drupal-commons-social-business-software) latest version 6.x-2.9 on MAMP 2.1.1 (clean install).

Drupal commons running very slow when I'm in the administer section. There's tons of modules and I'm not sure which are the key ones causing the slowness.

Need advice on that.

Comment: What are the modules enabled ?

Comment: You will never optimize a site by asking questions like that. Use xhprof and find out what is slow (which module, what query), then optimize. Otherwise you're just shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal for a Drupal site with a lot of modules. There are many SQL queries and huge use of memory to provide these admin pages, but if you look the site as a normal visitor, will see that this isn`t the same.

Commons, specifically, i had many issues related to very slow admin pages, when developing a large social network, with the many modules from Commons itself and many others specific from the project.

To improve this, you can:
 * tune your MySQL (the first thing to do is set your tables as INNODB, that you help a lot)
 * use memcached
 * use PHP APC
 * Look around http://web.archive.org/web/20110516021804/http://www.morningtime.com/Drupal-6x-Performance-Guide/513 (the MorningTime site removed the link, so you`ll only be able to see in the webarchive)